# KMZ into geotiff / gdal_translate

Tags: geotiff-tiff, gdal-translate, kmz

I have a kmz file which I would like to convert to geotiff. Unfortunately, gdal cannot handle kmz files from the rack. Obviously, there seems to be a driver available on: https://www.gdal.org/drv_libkml.html

How do I build this driver and use it?

Answer (score 3):

Try uncompressing/unzipping the KMZ file to a KML file first. Use any file extraction/unzip software (unzip/7-zip are good tools). Then you can use [gdal_rasterize](https://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html) to create the geotiff like the example below:

```
gdal_rasterize -burn 255 -burn 0 -burn 0 -ot Byte -ts 10000 10000 -a_srs EPSG:4326 -l somelayer somelayer.kml mynewgeotiff.tif
```