# Google Earth KMZ file converter to GeoTIFF

Tags: geotiff-tiff, software-recommendations, kmz

Any easy KMZ to GeoTIFF converters?

Mygeodata converter works perfect but its limited to 3 files per month.

I also can use QGIS to convert from KMZ to TIFF, it just takes a few extra steps.

Does anyone know of a free, simple online converter? Batch converter is even better.

Comment: Not an online one but check out this answer on doing in gdal. If you get that working it will be quick to do lots and an unlimited amount - just one line of code https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/298964/kmz-into-geotiff-gdal-translate

Comment: i ended up just using QGIS, Q never fails. Easier than coding

Comment: MyGeodata service allows you to convert up to 3 files per month. I agree, but have you tried to go with the incognito window? by changing VPN or something? I tried with incognito and I've gained 2x more as far as I remember.