# Convert KML to GeoTIFF with Python (osgeo.gdal)

Tags: python, gdal, kml, gdal-translate, osgeo

I have a KML file provided by a user that looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
  <Document>
    <GroundOverlay>
      <name>cool_data</name>
      <Icon>
        <href>cool_data.jpg</href>
      </Icon>
      <gx:LatLonQuad>
        <coordinates>
          -113.847312140212,47.1332041439526,1855.56303234312
          -113.895003003764,47.1463054962896,2273.85796258342
          -113.915190093483,47.1193944664833,2304.91498378361
          -113.849572771154,47.0981944903132,2005.60296315178
        </coordinates>
      </gx:LatLonQuad>
    </GroundOverlay>
    <Placemark>
      <name>cool_data</name>
      <visibility>0</visibility>
      <Point>
        <coordinates>
          -113.877880014095,47.1272016113816,0
        </coordinates>
      </Point>
    </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

I would like to convert this to a GeoTIFF using the functionality provided in `osgeo` lib. I have seen `gdal2tiles` but this seems to be useful for the GeoTIFF to KML conversion only. I believe the answer lies in the `osgeo.gdal` module translate functions but am unsure what the appropriate commands might be.

Opening this kml file with `ogr` shows that it does have a CRS by the way:

```
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AXIS["Latitude",NORTH],
    AXIS["Longitude",EAST],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
```

Comment: See here:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/298964/kmz-into-geotiff-gdal-translate

Comment: GDAL doesn't have a KML raster driver, only a KML vector driver.  You would need to extract the coordinates from the kml and use them (maybe as GCPs) to georeference the jpg and warp to geotiff.

Comment: For sure GDAL has a KML raster driver https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/kmlsuperoverlay.html.

Answer (score 0):

KML rasters are handled in GDAL with the KMLSUPEROVERLAY driver https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/kmlsuperoverlay.html.

What your KML file does is to tell that an image "cool_data.jpg" must be placed to cover a certain area on the ground. This georeferencing is done with a block

```
<gx:LatLonQuad>
        <coordinates>
          -113.847312140212,47.1332041439526,1855.56303234312
          -113.895003003764,47.1463054962896,2273.85796258342
          -113.915190093483,47.1193944664833,2304.91498378361
          -113.849572771154,47.0981944903132,2005.60296315178
        </coordinates>
</gx:LatLonQuad>
```

First problem that you may have is that the KML alone cannot show any raster data. You must have also the image file "cool_data.jpg" available. But even if you have that image you cannot convert it with GDAL because it is not aware of LatLonQuad that is an extension to the KML standard https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#gxlatlonquad.

> Description
>
> Allows nonrectangular quadrilateral ground overlays.

In this KML the corner points are really making a nonrectangular region

[image]

The best you can do with GDAL and the KMLSUPEROVERLAY driver https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/kmlsuperoverlay.html is to convert the LatLonQuad coordinates into LatLonBox

> <LatLonBox>
>
> Specifies where the top, bottom, right, and left sides of a bounding
> box for the ground overlay are aligned.

GDAL does support LatLonBox https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/6712. But the LatLonBox is rectangular and therefore your image would look badly distorted.

What I suggest to do is to convert the "cool_data.jpg" into GeoTIFF with gdal_translate and add corner coordinates that you can find from the KML file as ground control points `-gcp` https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html#cmdoption-gdal_translate-gcp.

Depending on what software you use it may be good to continue and warp the TIFF with ground control points physically into a north-up image with gdalwarp.